# mega menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, joomla1.5, joomla-template, megamenu

I have `Reviews` and `New Arrival` tabs in my website's in main menu and a submenu --
when i'm loading website.

My Home page it is not showing submenus but when hover over the tabs, then shows the submenus

for reference my website is http://www.babacomputers.com

i'm using `ja_zeolite_ii template`, `mega menu` and `joomla 1.5`

What am I doing wrong?

This is the html code of mega menu

```
<li class="mega haschild"><a title="Reviews" id="menu134" class="mega haschild" href="#"><span class="menu-title">Reviews</span><span class="menu-desc">&nbsp;</span></a><div class="childcontent cols1 " style="width: 252px;">
<div class="childcontent-inner-wrap" style="width: 202px;">
<div style="width: 200px; min-height: 102px;" class="childcontent-inner clearfix"><div style="width: 200px;" class="megacol column1 first"><ul class="megamenu level1"><li class="mega first"><a title="Laptops" id="menu129" class="mega first" href="/laptop-reviews.php"><span class="menu-title">Laptops</span></a></li><li class="mega"><a title="Accessories" id="menu135" class="mega" href="/accessories.php"><span class="menu-title">Accessories</span></a></li><li class="mega last"><a title="Tablets" id="menu136" class="mega last" href="/tablets.php"><span class="menu-title">Tablets</span></a></li></ul></div></div>
</div></div></li>
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to solve your problem. Unless you post some code.

Comment: Post the HTML for the menu and the javascript that handle it. That will be a start.

Comment: can you not check the website because i don't have much deeper knowledge in joomla but for searching html code i will need time and actually i mentioned website name but someone deleted it

Comment: now my website name is showing and it is www.babacomputers.com, i think you will be able to find problem

Comment: why others are editing my questions? Have you any problem? please dont delete it if you don't know what it is. and how administrator allow to edit authority to anyone, this is disgusting

Comment: Simple, we edit a question that not fit the [Stack Exchange FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) properly.

Comment: then can you not give the answer to this question, i also mentioned my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can goto template/css/menu/mega.css and change/ add some css

add below css

`li.haschild:hover .childcontent
{
    display:block;      }`

now then change below css

goto line no - 149 and right: 12em;

then save and now check.

this may help